# Prove that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are continuous and that $\int_{\gamma_1}F_1(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_2}F_2(z) dw$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega_1, \Omega_2 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and let $\gamma_1: [a,b] \to \Omega_1$, $\gamma_2: [c,d] \to \Omega_2$ be paths. Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $\gamma_1 \times \gamma_2$ and define $F_1: \Omega_1 \to \mathbb{C}$ and $F_2: \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{C}$ by

$$F_1 = \int_{\gamma_2} f(z,w)dw \; ,\;  F_2 = \int_{\gamma_1} f(z,w)dz$$

Prove that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are continuous and that
$$\int_{\gamma_1}F_1(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_2}F_2(z) dw$$

The way I approach this problem is after proving $F_1$ and $F_2$ are continuous. By using Fubini's theorem, we get

$$\int_{\gamma_1}F_1(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_1}\int_{\gamma_2} f(z,w)dzdw$$
$$= \int_{\gamma_2}  \int_{\gamma_1} f(z,w)dw dz = \int_{\gamma_2}F_2(z)dw$$

Hence, $$\int_{\gamma_2}F_1(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_1}F_2(z) dw$$

Is it the correct way to prove it; if it's not, can someone point me where am I wrong. Thank you.